# Detect scrollbar dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

What is wrong with the following code?

I need to detect and set width of 1 element based on if another element has scrollbar or not. this seems not working:

```
console.log("print Scroll..here...");
if(($(".printer-details-container").offsetHeight < $(".printer-details-container").scrollHeight) || ($(".printer-details-container").offsetWidth < $(".printer-details-container").scrollWidth)){
      // your element have overflow
      console.log("print Scroll..here...");
      $(".printer-header").css({"width":"96.9999%;"});
 }
 else{
      //your element don't have overflow
      console.log("no print Scroll..here...");
      $(".printer-header").css({"width":"100%;"});
      //console.log($(".printer-header").print-header.css({"width":"100%;"});
 }
```

Comment: What exactly is not working ? Can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: Condition is not working and we don't see a width setting up!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:

https://jsfiddle.net/4Lms5uzz/

At first the second div is set to 50 by 50.

If scroll is present in the #rules div, the dimensions of the second will be changed.

Basically the method is `divWithScrollbar.clientHeight < divWithScrollbar.scrollHeight`

scrollHeight gets the height of the content inside the div and clientHeight get the size of the div.

if the scrollHeight is smaller than scrollHeight, the scrollbar is visible.